# ES6 - How to keep JSON syntax with template literals?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, template-literals

When I do:

```
console.log(JSON)
```

it will display in JSON syntax in the console:

```
[ { test1: 'data',
    test2: 'data',
    test3: 'data' } ]
```

When I do:

```
console.log(`JSON Data\n\n${JSON}`)
```

it will display `[object Object]` so I do:

```
console.log(`JSON Data\n\n${JSON.stringify(JSON)}`)
```

which displays it in String syntax:

```
[{"test1":"data","test2":"data","test3":"data"}]
```

I want to do a console.log of the JSON data followed by some text in a template literal whilst keeping the JSON syntax, like so:

```
[ { test1: 'data',
test2: 'data',
test3: 'data' } ]

JSON Data Displayed Above
```

Comment: It's unclear what 'String syntax' and 'JSON syntax' are supposed to mean.

Comment: @estus `obj.toString()` and `JSON.stringify(obj)` i think thats clear from the context

Comment: @JonasW. Because the problem was poorly stated, I guess, so it should be clarified. According to the question, it's not true, 'String syntax'  == JSON.stringify(JSON), so it's unclear what 'JSON syntax' stands for, should it be colored and foldable like `console.log(JSON)` or just multiline.

Comment: +1 against inappropriate downvotes. Even _the JSON syntax (“an expandable/foldable hierarchical printing style”)_ is a wrong term, what it means can be easily figured out for this question. **Not knowing things cannot be a reason for downvotes**, but is a reason why we _ask_. If you find the expression wrong, just **`edit` it**.

Comment: @K._ It's unclear whether it's *an expandable/foldable hierarchical printing style* or just *hierarchical printing style*, and this isn't a reader's business to deduce the meaning of it.

Comment: Would it help if I add the outputs of each console.log I put in the question?

Comment: @Edward This is always helpful to both posters and future readers. It's also necessary to clarify whether you're after *multiline* output or *multiline, colored, foldable* output (the latter is impossible with template literals, the answers address that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a template literal, the result is a string. If you want to add texts labels before/after the logged data, or other values, separate them by comma:

```js
var data = { a: 1, b: [1, 2] };
console.log('Before:', data, '\n\nJSON Data Displayed Above');

console.log(data, '\n\nAfter');

console.log('Before\n', data, '\n\nAfter');
```

Comment: Is there a way for the \n\n to work without having to put a String before the JSON data in the console.log()? Because the newline only works when a String is added before the JSON data.

Comment: It works without adding a string before the data. See updated example. Anyway, you can always add an empty string to the start.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer, I must be doing something wrong for the console.log to not work with just the JSON data before it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could change the way objects are converted to a string:

```
 Object.prototype.toString = function(){
   return JSON.stringify(this);
 };
```

Now this will work as expected:

```
 console.log(`JSON Data\n\n${JSON}`)
```

Comment: Every time you modify Object.prototype, God kills a kitten.

Comment: So I assume this is a bad approach with your comment @estus or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Edward Yes. Built-in prototypes should be never modified (with the exception of polyfills). I guess the answer serves educational purpose.

Comment: @estus no actually not. yes, one needs to be careful when working with native prototypes. But that doesnt mean one cannot mofify them at all.

Comment: One surely can, this cannot be physically prohibited. But this is bad practice that is discouraged in JS, for a very good reason. The code above will break every single piece of code that relies on original Object.prototype.toString behaviour.

Comment: A *lot* of libs detect object type with `obj.toString()` and parse `[object Object]` string, and this is a considered a legit way, it relies on how JS works. I believe this proves the point. One cannot be careful enough to avoid situations like that. Even if a dev thinks that he/she is smart to not break anything, there can be [another smart guy who thinks the same way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49325402/looking-for-hacks-to-shim-objects-when-their-prototype-are-sealed).

Answer (score 0):

`console` implementation is browser-specific. In modern browsers, objects can be outputted in human-readable form.

Modern implementations support multiple `console` arguments (as another answer suggests):

```
console.log(`JSON Data`, json);
```

This may not work as expected in legacy browsers; multiple `console.log` arguments were originally intended for [string substitutions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Outputting_text_to_the_console), and there may be problems if first argument accidentally contains substitution syntax, e.g. `%s`.

A compatible, cross-platform way to achieve string-only, human-readable output is to configure object stringification:

```
console.log(`JSON Data\n\n${JSON.stringify(json, null, 2)}`)
```

The benefit of this approach is that the output stays the same everywhere, whether it's legacy browser or `console.log` call that was intercepted by a logger.